# Prisma : how can I add a column on a query return?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

Let's say I have a table `User` with a name and an Id and a table `Post` with a name and a content. The two tables are linked through a many to many relation ( one post can have many users / authors and each user can have many posts )

Example :

```
model User {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  posts         users_to_posts[]
}

model Post {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  users         users_to_posts[]
}

model user_to_post {
  user          user? @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id       Int
  post          signe? @relation(fields: [post_id], references: [id])
  post_id       Int
  @@id([user_id, post_id])
}
```

What I would like to do is query the user table and have the top 10 users who have written the most posts.

However, I do not wish do just return a combination of user + post count but have a full return of the user, his Id and the amount of posts he have written as a separate key in the returned JSON

Example of what I am attempting to get ( using nextJS ) :

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()


export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const ret = await prisma.user.findMany({
        include: {
            posts: {
                select: {
                    post: true
                }
            }
        }
        // include post count
        // order by post count
        // limit 10
    });
    res.status(200).json(ret)
}
```

As you can see I do not have the 'count' column in my table and it has to be inserted during the query

My best alternative right now is to parse the obtained json ( the ret variable ) and do everything through typescript but this is far from ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orderBy` to sort `user` records by the `count` of `posts` they have. Furthermore, you can use the `take` operator to limit the number of records (works similar to the `LIMIT` command in SQL). Finally, to include the `count` of posts, you can add that inside `include`.

Here is the query you're looking for

```js
await prisma.user.findMany({
    orderBy: {
        posts: {
            _count: "desc",
        },
    },
    take: 10,
    include: {
        _count: {
            select: {
                posts: true,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

From what I understand from your question, you only want to return the `count` of posts, not the post records themselves. However, if you also want to return the post records, you can also add that to the `include` statement, like you are currently doing.

Further Reading from the Docs for the operators used:

- [Sorting by relation aggregate values](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value)
- [Select Relation Count](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing#count-relations)